# How to add text to Android's Action Bar Home button?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an app and I have managed to add an image for the home button in the action bar.

I did this using the actionbar.setIcon() method.

The image is essentially a blank button image. I want to be able to add the text "exit" on top of the image. Is there a way to do something like this ?

Comment: so far i know no. But you can make a button direct with your text "exit"

Answer (score 0):

so far i know no. But you can make an image button direct with your text "exit"

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround.
I made the home button hidden using :

Actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

and then added a button to the action bar, with the image
and the text on the button.